# Is it possible to override the behavior of tqdm.auto in a loaded library?

Tags: tqdm

I am using an Emacs interface to Jupyter notebooks which means that even though `tqdm` detects that I am in a Jupyter notebook, I would like it to update the progress bar as if it were in a terminal (i.e. I use `from tqdm import tqdm`) in my Emacs interface.

However, some libraries (e.g. Huggingface) automatically detect whether or not I am in a notebook and use the specified tqdm progress bar. I would like to override this to use tqdm.std. Is this possible?

My current fix is to go into the source code and replace: `#from tqdm.auto import tqdm` with `from tqdm import tqdm` everywhere.